# Angular 6 Auxillary routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-auxiliary-routes

am trying to do the following

[image: sample layout of my application]

I successfully able to navigate to side nav bar using router-outlet and app.routing-module.ts. I tried auxiliary routing for the tabs inside the Nav4 component. But it got failed. Can anyone help me out on this?

app.routing-module.ts
after importing the required components

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: Nav1Component},
    { path: 'nav2', component: Nav2Component},
    { path: 'nav3', component: Nav3Component},
    {
      path: 'nav4', component: Nav4Component, children: [
          { path: 'tab1', component: Tab1Component, outlet: 'configureoutlet'},
          { path: 'tab2', component: Tab2Component, outlet: 'configureoutlet'}
          { path: 'tab3', component: Tab3Component, outlet: 'configureoutlet'},
          { path: 'tab4', component: Tab4Component, outlet: 'configureoutlet'},
          { path: 'tab5', component: Tab5Component, outlet: 'configureoutlet'},
    ]
 }
];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Nav4component.html

```
<h4>Nav 4 general content</h4>    
<ul>
  <li routerlink="['/nav4', { outlets: { configureoutlet: ['tab1'] }} ]" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 1</li>
  <li routerlink="['/nav4', { outlets: { configureoutlet: ['tab2'] }} ]" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 2</li>
  <li routerlink="['/nav4', { outlets: { configureoutlet: ['tab3'] }} ]" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 3</li>
  <li routerlink="['/nav4', { outlets: { configureoutlet: ['tab4'] }} ]" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 4</li>
  <li routerlink="['/nav4', { outlets: { configureoutlet: ['tab5'] }} ]" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 5</li>
</ul>
<router-outlet name='configureoutlet'></router-outlet>
```

When I run the application am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify relative path, something like this

```
<li routerlink="['tab1']" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 1</li>
<li routerlink="['tab2']" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 2</li>
<li routerlink="['tab3']" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 3</li>
<li routerlink="['tab4']" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 4</li>
<li routerlink="['tab5']" routerLinkActive='active'>Tab 5</li>
```

And router outlet will be simply,

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```